# Get list of files from specific Folder in Android Q

Tags: android, kotlin, local-storage, android-10.0

I am trying to access the specific folder in android Q but the app is getting crashed.

I am using below code which is working fine till Android PIE but it is not working in Android Q

```
    val directory = File(path)
    val files = directory.listFiles()


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Getting bellow error

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: You [do not have filesystem access to most of external storage on Android Q](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Answer (score 2):

With Android Q file interface can't be used to access public directories, unless you use the `requestLegacyStorage` in your app manifest (not raccomanded since it won't work anymore with Android R). To access the directory you need to use the `DocumentFile` class, for example:

```
DocumentFile f = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
f.listFiles();
```